# What Loss function to use for binary classification in CNN using float labels?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, classification, loss-function

So I am building a CNN that gets images using labels that go from 0 to 1.

What I mean is that I am trying to perform detection of **one** thing in the image and each image has a label between 0 and 1 that stands for the probability of said type of event being in that image.

I want to output this probability so I am using a sigmoid activation function in the output layer but I am having trouble in deciding what loss function makes sense in this situation. If my labels were 0 and 1s I would use Binary CrossEntropy but does that still make sense when my labels are floats ranging from 0 to 1?

Cheers.

Comment: you should probably ask this on the data science stack exchange instead (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for `logits` (output of last linear layer) not for output probabilities

```py
def loss(logits, soft_labels):
    anti_soft_labels = 1 - soft_labels
    return soft_labels * tf.nn.softplus(-logits) 
+ anti_soft_labels * tf.nn.softplus(logits) + tf.math.xlogy(soft_labels, soft_labels) + tf.math.xlogy(anti_soft_labels, anti_soft_labels)

loss(logits=tf.constant([10., 0, -10]), soft_labels=tf.constant([1., 0.5, 0.]))
# [4.53989e-05, 0.00000e+00, 4.53989e-05]
```

If you need to have 0 as minimal loss value for any soft label use

````py
def loss(logits, soft_labels):
    anti_soft_labels = 1 - soft_labels
    return soft_labels * tf.nn.softplus(-logits) \
        + anti_soft_labels * tf.nn.softplus(logits) \
        + tf.math.xlogy(soft_labels, soft_labels) \
        + tf.math.xlogy(anti_soft_labels, anti_soft_labels)

loss(logits=tf.constant([10., 0, -10]), soft_labels=tf.constant([1., 0.5, 0.]))
# [4.53989e-05, 0.00000e+00, 4.53989e-05]```
````