# Is the loss function wrong in the following code for binary classification of images using soft labels? Or is there some other problem?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

We are using CNN to classify images with labels 0 and 1 in tensorflow.

However, in reality, images have probability values between 0 and 1, not one-hot labels of 0 and 1. Images with probabilities in the range [0, 0.5) are labeled 0, and images in the range [0.5, 1.0] are labeled 1. I want to check whether the classification performance is better if binary classification is performed using soft labels between 0 and 1 instead of one-hot labels.

The code below is an example of binary classification only with data labeled 0 and 1 in the cifar10 dataset.
In the code below, the accuracy is about 98% without 'making soft labels part', but about 48% with 'making soft labels part'.

Should I modify the 'BinaryCrossEntropy_custom' function, which is the loss function, to solve the problem? Or is something else wrong?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71387123/18525539) says that using logits solves it. I understand `soft_labels` argument, but what value should I put in `logits` argument in this example code?

```
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.applications import vgg16
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

# Rewrite the binary cross entropy function. We will modify this function to return a loss that fits the soft label later.
def BinaryCrossEntropy_custom(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1 - K.epsilon())
    term_0 = (1 - y_true) * K.log(1 - y_pred + K.epsilon())
    term_1 = y_true * K.log(y_pred + K.epsilon())
    return -K.mean(term_0 + term_1, axis=0)

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

# Only data with labels 0 and 1 are used.
train_ind01 = np.where((train_labels == 0) | (train_labels == 1))[0]
test_ind01 = np.where((test_labels == 0) | (test_labels == 1))[0]
train_images = train_images[train_ind01, :, :, :]
test_images = test_images[test_ind01, :, :, :]
train_labels = train_labels[train_ind01, :]
test_labels = test_labels[test_ind01, :]

train_labels = np.array(train_labels).astype('float64')
test_labels = np.array(test_labels).astype('float64')

# making soft labels part start
# Samples with label 0 are replaced with labels in the range [0,0.2],
# and samples with label 1 are replaced by labels in the range [0.8, 1.0].
sampl_train = np.random.uniform(low=-0.2, high=0.2, size=train_labels.shape)
sampl_test = np.random.uniform(low=-0.2, high=0.2, size=test_labels.shape)
train_labels = train_labels + sampl_train
test_labels = test_labels + sampl_test
train_labels = np.clip(train_labels, 0.0, 1.0)
test_labels = np.clip(test_labels, 0.0, 1.0)
# making soft labels part end

vgg = vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
output = vgg.layers[-1].output
output = layers.Flatten()(output)
output = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(output)
output = layers.Dropout(0.2)(output)
output = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(output)
output = layers.Dropout(0.2)(output)
predictions = layers.Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid")(output)
model = Model(inputs=vgg.input, outputs=predictions)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=.0001), loss=BinaryCrossEntropy_custom, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=100,
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='val_accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.ylim([0.5, 1])
plt.legend(loc='lower right')

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)

print(test_acc)
```

The console output with making soft labels part is

```
Epoch 1/100
2022-09-16 15:29:29.136931: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:366] Loaded cuDNN version 8101
313/313 [==============================] - 17s 42ms/step - loss: 0.2951 - accuracy: 0.4779 - val_loss: 0.2775 - val_accuracy: 0.4650
Epoch 2/100
313/313 [==============================] - 12s 38ms/step - loss: 0.2419 - accuracy: 0.4931 - val_loss: 0.2488 - val_accuracy: 0.4695
Epoch 3/100
313/313 [==============================] - 12s 39ms/step - loss: 0.2290 - accuracy: 0.4978 - val_loss: 0.2424 - val_accuracy: 0.4740
Epoch 4/100
313/313 [==============================] - 12s 39ms/step - loss: 0.2161 - accuracy: 0.5002 - val_loss: 0.2404 - val_accuracy: 0.4765
Epoch 5/100
313/313 [==============================] - 12s 39ms/step - loss: 0.2139 - accuracy: 0.5007 - val_loss: 0.2620 - val_accuracy: 0.4730
Epoch 6/100
313/313 [==============================] - 12s 38ms/step - loss: 0.2118 - accuracy: 0.5023 - val_loss: 0.2480 - val_accuracy: 0.4745
Epoch 7/100
313/313 [==============================] - 12s 38ms/step - loss: 0.2097 - accuracy: 0.5019 - val_loss: 0.2350 - val_accuracy: 0.4775
Epoch 8/100
313/313 [==============================] - 12s 39ms/step - loss: 0.2098 - accuracy: 0.5024 - val_loss: 0.2289 - val_accuracy: 0.4780
Epoch 9/100
313/313 [==============================] - 12s 38ms/step - loss: 0.2034 - accuracy: 0.5039 - val_loss: 0.2364 - val_accuracy: 0.4780
Epoch 10/100
313/313 [==============================] - 12s 39ms/step - loss: 0.2025 - accuracy: 0.5040 - val_loss: 0.2481 - val_accuracy: 0.4720
```

Comment: While it is true that cross-entropy is no longer a "valid" loss function for soft labels from a maximum likelihood point of view, the real issue here is that accuracy becomes a meaningless metric as it checks for exact equality of (thresholded) outputs to targets and it's very unlikely that your model outputs match the soft targets to the last floating point digit. So you should really think about a different metric to use, or do accuracy evaluation with "hard" labels instead.

Comment: @xdurch0 it was probably enough to say that he just need to use `binary_accuracy`

Comment: That is not at all what I said, and it's not true. Using `accuracy` as a metric already makes keras choose binary or categorical based on the context, and explicitly choosing `binary_accuracy` here makes no difference.

Comment: @xdurch0 thank you for your comment. Answers to questions similar to this one were of the same opinion as you.